# Using iconv to convert strings to ISO-8859-1 in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, iconv, iso-8859-1

I want to convert strings from the GBK character set to ISO-8859-1.

I have tried to use the iconv library, but `iconv()` always returns -1, and `errno` decodes to *"Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"*.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post a ten-twenty line program that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Do those strings contain non-ASCII (e.g. Chinese) characters? That could be the reason why a conversion routine fails to convert them.

Comment: yes, string contain non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have opened the conversion descriptor without `//TRANSLIT` or `//IGNORE`, then `iconv()` will return an error when the input character cannot be represented in the target character set.  Since ISO-8859-1 cannot represent most GBK characters, this is likely what is happening.  The following example works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>

int main()
{
    char *gbk_str = "GBK \xB5\xE7\xCA\xD3\xBB\xFA";
    char dest_str[100];
    char *out = dest_str;
    size_t inbytes = strlen(gbk_str);
    size_t outbytes = sizeof dest_str;
    iconv_t conv = iconv_open("ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", "GBK");

    if (conv == (iconv_t)-1) {
        perror("iconv_open");
        return 1;
    }

    if (iconv(conv, &gbk_str, &inbytes, &out, &outbytes) == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("iconv");
        return 1;
    }

    dest_str[sizeof dest_str - outbytes] = 0;
    puts(dest_str);

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>(I hope that GBK string isn't obscene, I have no idea what it means!)</sub>

Comment: i compile you example,open the conversion descriptor with //TRANSLIT,it still failed. if open the conversion descriptor with //IGNORE,it can convert a success,but it ignore non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @maixl: Which `iconv` implementation are you using?

Comment: Don't worry. The GBK string is just `电视机`, which means television.